# Power BI - Calculating Averages (based on multiple values & filters) and Display on a Card

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset of 300+ items that is in essence a project list for a team of 17 people.  Projects in the list have three statuses:

- Not Started
- In Progress
- Completed

A sample dataset would look something like this:

```
Alice ProjectA NotStarted
Alice ProjectB InProgress
Bob   ProjectC InProgress
Eve   ProjectD InProgress
Bob   ProjectE Completed
*....insert 300 rows....*
Bob   ProjectX InProgress
```

I would like to display a card that show the average amount of In Progress projects there are across the team.

Using the data above as an example:

- Alice => 1 InProgress project
- Bob => 2 InProgress projects
- Eve => 1 InProgress project

So the card would dispay:

```
1.3
```

Comment: Create a column similar to: `In Progress? = if(Column3 = "InProgress", 1,blank())` Then create a measure `Card Measure = sum(In Progress?)/People on team`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without a helper column. Create a measure with the formula

```
projectCount = CALCULATE(COUNTA(Projects[project]),Projects[status]="InProgress")
```

and one for distinct count of teams

```
Team count = DISTINCTCOUNT('Projects'[team])
```

Now you can create a measure for the percentage and use that measure in the card

```
percentage = (Projects[projectCount]/Projects[Team count])/100
```

[image]

Or, do it in one fell swoop formula

```
inProgressPercentage = (CALCULATE(COUNTA(Projects[project]),Projects[status]="InProgress")/DISTINCTCOUNT('Projects'[team]))/100
```

With the measure selected, click the Modeling ribbon to set the desired format for the number.

[image]